# ionic3 allow keyboard to push view up

Tags: ios, keyboard, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm using Ionic ver 3.9.2

I'd like to push the view up on iOS so my footer is not hidden.

[image]

Don't want the keyboard to cover my footer

[image]

On Android, I can use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and this magically shrink the view. Is there any way to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `onKeyboardShow()` and `onKeyboardHide()` of the [Ionic Keyboard Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/) to know when to resize the screen to exclude the keyboard.

Try making the following changes and see if it does what you want. You will need to tweak the keyboard_height and the easing to properly get this working

**app.html**

```
<ion-nav .... [style.height]="nav_style"></ion-nav>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
keyboard_height: number = 200;
nav_style: string = null;

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard, private platform: Platform, ...){
    if(this.platform.is('ios')){
        this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow(() => {
            this.nav_style = 'calc(100%-' + this.keyboard_height + 'px)';
        });
        this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide(() => {
            this.nav_style = null;
        });
    }
}
```

**app.scss**

```
ion-nav{
    transition: height 0.2s ease-out
}
```